# Setting active spring profile using gradle in docker does not have any effect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I have a spring boot project with the following files:

- application.yml (the default)
- application-dev.yml (obviously my dev config)
- Dockerfile-dev
- docker-compose-dev.yml

My `Dockerfile-dev` contains the following setps:

```
FROM gradle:5.2.1-jre11 AS BUILDSTAGE

USER root
WORKDIR /output

COPY . .

RUN gradle application:build -Dspring.profiles.active=dev --no-daemon
RUN find /output/application/build/libs

FROM openjdk:11-jre

WORKDIR /app

COPY application/wait-for-it.sh ./wait-for-it.sh
COPY --from=BUILDSTAGE /output/application/build/libs/application-*.jar ./application.jar

RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

Please dont get confused by the `wait-for-it.sh` this is a simple shell script which is making sure that spring boot is starting up after the database is started.

As you can see I build with `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` so from my understanding this is setting the active spring profile to `dev` which should make sure that the `application-dev.yml` config is getting used and not `application.yml`.

My `build.gradle` contains:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

My `docker-compose` file is using the `Dockerfile-dev`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.18
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "test"
      MYSQL_USER: "test"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mysql"
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: application/Dockerfile-dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
```

And when I do `docker-compose -f application/docker-compose-dev.yml up --force-recreate --build -V --remove-orphans` I get the following output:

```
Building app
Step 1/12 : FROM gradle:5.2.1-jre11 AS BUILDSTAGE
 ---> d57eadc2e4d3
Step 2/12 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 72aa645c307e
Step 3/12 : WORKDIR /output
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 327fd32c6c3d
Step 4/12 : COPY . .
 ---> 055d0c0c09e9
Step 5/12 : RUN gradle application:build -Dspring.profiles.active=dev --no-daemon
 ---> Running in c2a23d7fc2b3
```

So this seems to be fine. But later in the logs when the spring application is getting started:

```
app_1  |
app_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
app_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
app_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
app_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
app_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
app_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
app_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)
app_1  |
app_1  | 2019-11-27 09:47:15,388 INFO  [main] [d.f.backend.ApplicationKt] - Starting ApplicationKt on 5f5fc7f3dddf with PID 1 (/app/application.jar started by root in /app)
app_1  | 2019-11-27 09:47:15,403 INFO  [main] [d.f.backend.ApplicationKt] - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

As you can see `No active profile set` so it is going to use the default, which is `application.yml`.
So seems like I have a misunderstanding / misconfiguration how to set the active spring profile in my setup. How can I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the profile when building the app, instead you need to set the profile when you are running the app (via the entrypoint):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "application.jar"
```